# CSS: help positioning a clipped image in Chrome/Safari. IE and FireFox look good

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-position

Clipping an image with CSS and everything looks great with FireFox and IE7+, but Chrome and Safari are not accepting the `position:absolute`very nicely. Instead of staying "relative" to the parent containers, it's in fact using the absolute positioning coordinates.

I've tried putting containers and positioning those in different ways, but I'm not having any luck.

Unfortunately, I can not provide any example directly.

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="grayBkgd marginTop10Px grid_3 grayVideoContainer alpha">
    <a href="?ytID" class="noUnderlineHover curser-pointer">
        <div class="clip">
            <img src="an image" alt="" />
        </div><br />
        <div class="videoTextInfo">
            <p class="videoTitle">Optical Windows Overview
            </p>
        </div>
        <p class="grayText" style="float:right">0:37 mins</p>
    </a>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
        .grayVideoContainer{
            text-align:center;
            padding:3px 0 5px 0
        }
        .clip img {
            position:absolute;
            margin-left:-58px;
            clip:rect(12px 120px 79px 0)
        }
        .videoTextInfo {
            min-height:60px;
            padding:70px 5px 0 5px;
            color:#000
        }
        .grayText {
            float:right;
            margin-top:-10px;
            padding:0 5px 0 0   
        }
</style>
```

Any ideas?

I tried looking for JQuery plugins to clip the image and see if I'd have an easier time positioning the elements, but I didn't have very much luck finding any promising plugins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are the parent containers positioned at all? If not, try to add `position: relative;` to the parent of the child that's `position: absolute;`. The relative positioning won't change the parent's position in the flow of your site but will allow you to have absolutely positioned children.

Comment: Won't I didn't add were all of my CSS attempts. I added position: relative to the parent containers. I too would have imagined that would have been the fix.

Comment: It would be more "less-impossible" to help you if we could see your CSS, through something such as http://jsfiddle.net/ - without knowing what's in all those classes in your parent it's pretty impossible to know what's causing the issue.

Comment: Actually, just figured it out. It had to do with both of your answers really. I was putting position:relative on the wrong parent container and then I put the left attribute back. 

Because you said what I was thinking, I went back and tried it and realized I wasn't seeing the most direct parent div. Added it there and it worked!

Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, I know haha. There's a lot of answers that people weren't able to help out though or I ended up figuring it out on my own and I don't want to accept a wrong answer and potentially screw someone else up. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

An absolutely positioned element's position should be specified with `top`, `left`, `right`, and/or `bottom`.

See: http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_class_position.asp

The `margin-left` on `.clip img` I might expect not to work.

Comment: Yeah, I know all about that and have tried it. Not the issue.

Comment: I did end up using the left attribute again, but I think the other guys answer enabled me to figure it out 8-). Thanks for taking the time to help!